# Change Tab's Text from the Fragment

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to do something very simple. I have 2 tabs, one showing information about the breed of a dog and the other is showing a list of reviews that people have written describing the breed. I would like to include the number of reviews that were written in the Tab as well so it would look like so:

Breed Info   |   Reviews(19)

The issue is that I need to download said review data first in order to see the number of reviews there is on the tab.

So what I thought of as a solution was to add the tab first in my BreedProfile.java (ShelockActivity)

```
ActionBar.Tab reviewTab= ab.newTab();
reviewTab.setText("Reviews");
mTabsAdapter.addTab(reviewTab, DogReviewFragment.class, null);
```

Then in my BreedProfileReviewFragment.java I would download the reviews then update the reviewTab text by doing so:

```
getActivity().getActionBar().getTabAt(1).setText("Reviews 10");
```

However, the above method does not exist according to the LogCat.

```
03-05 18:15:26.460: E/AndroidRuntime(1286): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-05 18:15:26.460: E/AndroidRuntime(1286): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getActionBar
```

So my question is, is it possible to access the TAB from the FRAGMENT to change the TEXT property of the TAB after it is added? If it is, how can I achieve that?

NOTES:

1. I cannot download the reviews together with the breed information because the API's are separate.
2. The BreedProfile.java Originates from a list of Breeds in a ListActivity BreedList.java.

Comment: I figured it out already. Basically in order to access the tabs, I should be using:

getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().getTabAt(1).setText("Review(10)");
instead of what I previously used because I'm using actionbarsherlock.

I hope someone else would find this useful.

Good day!

Answer (score 2):

You can implement an `Interface`. so you can run the code at the parent activity of the fragment.

create your interface in your fragment like below:.

```
public interface OnQuestionSelectedListener {
 void onQuestionSelected(int Position, boolean isFirstTime);
}
```

Implement it at your parent activity side like below:

```
public class YourParentActivity extends Activity implements YourFragment.OnQuestionSelectedListener{
       @Override
    public void onQuestionSelected(int position, boolean isFirstTime) {
        // your code.
         }
}
```

Call it from your fragment like below:

```
((YourParentActivityName)getActivity()).onQuestionSelected(position, true);
```

(You can make changes in the code as per your need)
It is a very good practice to transfer all your logic of fragment to its parent because what I believe is fragment use for your UI part and `Interface` provide us a good way to transfer the fragment message to the parent.Do all the activity at parent and transfer the result to corresponding fragment.

Hope this will help.